# Solar setup for well pump

Tags: solar-power, batteries

The electricity where I live is pretty expensive at about almost 30 cents a KWh, so I'm considering setting up a solar system. I got 3 100 Watt Polycrystalline solar panels a while ago, pretty cheap. I live in the Caribbean, so I have access to a lot of sun. I am planning to connect my 1 HP well pump to the system. It runs about 350 Watts and starts at about 800 Watts. I plan to maybe connect my refrigerator later on which runs at about the same wattage.

I was thinking of getting an MPPT Solar Controller. Not sure if 60 amps is too much. I plan to get more solar panels later on with higher wattage. Also thinking of getting either a 2,000 or 3,000 Power Inverter. Still not sure which battery to get.

Could you guys give me some recommendations on a good setup for what I plan to power and some room to grow.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you planning to use a battery in this system?

Comment: Yes. Not sure whether to use 12V or 24V, but seeing how hard to get 24V, probably stick to 12V...

Comment: Been looking at the GIANDEL 2200W Pure Sine Wave Power Inverter 12V DC to 120V AC with 20A Solar Charge Control. Although it is PWM and not MPPT, it's at a reasonable price for an all in one, for what I have.

Comment: The question as written is quite broad -- can you narrow to a specific component? As a side note -- if you are considering expanding the system, I'd consider going for an MPPT charger and a higher voltage. The lower battery voltage will limit the amount you can expand later on.